# GPU problem for CUDA 11.0 and cuDNN 8.0.2

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have the CUDA 11.0 and cuDNN 8.0.2, which are the recommended setup

I have tensorflow-gpu 2.3 and keras 2.4

However the GPUs are not used and I don't know why.

by giving the following command lines

```
sess = tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None)
print("GPU available? ", sess)
built = tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()
print("tf is built with CUDA? ", built)
gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
cpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('CPU')
print("Num GPUs used: ", len(gpus))
print("Num CPUs used: ", len(cpus))
print(tf.sysconfig.get_build_info())
```

The output is the following:

```
GPU available?  False
tf is built with CUDA?  True
Num GPUs used:  0
Num CPUs used:  1
{'cuda_version': '10.1', 'cudnn_version': '7', 'cuda_compute_capabilities': ['sm_35', 'sm_37', 'sm_52', 'sm_60', 'sm_61', 'compute_70'], 'cpu_compiler': '/usr/bin/gcc-5', 'is_rocm_build': False, 'is_cuda_build': True}
```

it comes with the following error:

```
 W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.10.1'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
 I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
 I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
 I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
 I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
 I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
 W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1753] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
```

Comment: what is the result of running `tf.sysconfig.get_build_info()`  ? You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63602327/edit) with this info, you do not need to put it into the comments.

Comment: With your latest edit, it's evident that your tf 2.3 is built against CUDA 10.1 You cannot use CUDA 11.0 as a substitute for that.

Comment: I don't know how did this inconsistency happen. How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you follow the steps mentioned in the answer and see if your error is resolved. You have to download the exact version specified.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in Tensorflow documentation. The software requirements are as follows.

```
Nvidia gpu drivers - 418.x or higher
Cuda - 10.1 (TensorFlow >= 2.1.0)
cuDNN - 7.6
```

See [Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements)

You must have a python version between 3.5 - 3.8.

Along with that you need Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019.

You can download that here. [Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

Check the full system requirements here [Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-requirements)

Don't forget to add cuda and cudnn in your system path. See [Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#windows_setup)

Comment: Im using python 3.6 with a Linux setup. But I don't want to downgrade the CUDA version.

Comment: `libcudart.so.10.1` is a file found in Cuda 10.1. Tensorflow at the moment doesn't support Cuda 11.

Comment: That means im forced to downgrade it to Cuda 10.1 to use it with tensorflow 2.3? Isn't there any other possibility?
It seems that tensorflow-nightly is an option as mentioned here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42162

Comment: You can use tensorflow-nightly build but since it is under construction there are chances that it might break. Its always better to use stable versions of the software.

Comment: If the solution worked can you please accept and upvote.

Comment: I installed tf-nightly 2.4 in my env, but still getting the same errors. Should I import it or should I remove tensorflow?

Comment: I removed tensorflow to use tf-nightly and the following info comes out:
    
    GPU available?  False
    tf is built with CUDA?  True
    Num GPUs used:  0
    Num CPUs used:  1
    try:  OrderedDict([('cpu_compiler', '/usr/bin/gcc-5'), ('cuda_compute_capabilities', ['sm_35', 'sm_37', 'sm_52', 'sm_60', 'sm_61', 'compute_70']), ('cuda_version', '11.0'), ('cudnn_version', '8'), ('is_cuda_build', True), ('is_rocm_build', False)])

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/orgs/tensorflow/projects/10#card-43097878). The build is still in progress. Since tf-nightly just clones the current repo something might be broken. From [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42047) we can ascertain that tf-nightly now supports both ubuntu and windows. So you have to follow the same procedure as mentioned in the answer in that order. Also, remove other versions of software to avoid conflicts. And then finally create a virtualenv and install tf-nightly.

Answer (score 0):

This solution clears the issue completely in my case even my system is set up with CUDA 10.2. Tensorflow probably requires something from CUDA 10.1, I guess.

```sh
conda install cudatoolkit=10.1
```

Check https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38578#issuecomment-710104168

Comment: Not everyone uses Anaconda